# How do you determine the likelihood of all 0s or all 1s in an infinite coin toss?

Tags: probability

A {0,1} faced coin is tossed an infinite number of times, the probability of 1 in any toss being equal to p $\in (0,1)$.  The resulting sequence $\omega$ is parsed into consecutive blocks of increasing length: 2,4,6,....  What is the likelihood that in infinitely many of these blocks, the first half of the terms are either all 0s or all 1s?

Comment: Have you seen the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Borel-Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) states that if $E_n$ is a sequence of events and $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\Pr(E_n) < \infty$, then the probability that infinitely many of those events occur is $0$.

For this problem, let $E_n$ be the event that in the $n$-th block, the first half is all $0$'s or all $1$'s.

Now, you just need to calculate $\Pr(E_n)$ for each $n$ and then compute $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\Pr(E_n)$.

If $\displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\Pr(E_n) < \infty$, then you can apply the Borel-Cantelli lemma to this problem.

Comment: yes i have heard of the BC lemma.  But how do I compute P(En) ? I understand it is the event that in the nth block the first half are all 0s or all 1s.  But I was wondering if you could give me a concrete example of En.  For example $E_1$ or $E_5$

Comment: Ok, lets calculate $E_5$. The fifth block has ten coin tosses. What is the probability that the first half (just the first five of these coin toss) are all heads? What is the probability that these five coin tosses are all tails?

Comment: I see it now.  Its the infinite sum of $1/2^n$ which converges to 2,hence less than \infty so i can apply BC-lemma and conclude the measure is 0 for infinitely many blocks.

Comment: Almost. You should have gotten $\Pr(E_n) = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ not $\frac{1}{2^n}$. Remember that the $n$ coin tosses can be all heads OR all tails.

Comment: $\Pr (E_n) = 2^{-2n} = 4^{-n}$.  The $n^{th}$ block has $2n$ coin flips.  There are $2^{2n}$ possible results of this, only one of which has all heads in the first half, and all tails in the second. @user11460

Comment: The question as the OP has written it says "What is the likelihood that in infinitely many of these blocks, the first half of the terms are either all 0s or all 1s?" So this only considers the first $n$ flips in each block, and both all heads and all tails in this block are counted.

Comment: Point.  Missed that.

Comment: "Its the infinite sum of 1/2^n" In fact, one would expect some series involving p^n and (1-p)^n.